# Reinstalled 15.10 and now steam controller unusable in game

Tags: 15.10, steam

My previous install had issues that seemed to revolve around updating from 15.04 on a machine with full disk encryption on initial install. Things like using the latest kernel would hang on passphrase and htop showing significantly more memory usage than normal for no discernible reason. These were bearable until I got my steam controller and tried to play, steam big picture seems to have a larger resource footprint than the normal client and crashed my games repeatedly. To be clear, the controller was working as intended both on desktop and in-game before reinstall.

After reinstalling, I downloaded the bare minimum of what I had on my machine before, ubuntu-restricted-extras vlc htop aptitude and steam. I did not try the controller right away, work got busy, so now about a month later, steam controller wont work. On wireless alone, the controller turns on and the haptic feedback is there but nothing happens on screen, same in BP mode. on wired the controller acts like the mouse portion of the presets on desktop and BP mode, in-game is more of the same and I cant access controller customization or community through the steam button on the controller.

Xinput has both valve software wireless controller when the dongle is plugged in and valve software wired controller when the usb is plugged. I have tried all of the valve troubleshooting suggestions and browsed about both here and steam's forums for a solution on and off for the last two days with no luck.

I hope I have been clear enough about my problem and what I have already tried, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself with help from a reddit post and some additional googling that came from said post.

There is a typo in `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-steam-perms.rules` that needs to be edited from `*********=="***", ATTRS{idVendor}=="****", ATTRS{idVendor}=="****", ****="****"` to `*********=="***", ATTRS{idVendor}=="****", ATTRS{idProduct}=="****", ****="****"` on both lines this appears.

I replaced information that I did not need to edit with `*` in the unlikly event that those are specific to my machine and could cause issues for others if pasted directly as is.

Plugging in the steam controller and starting Big Picture after doing this allowed for a firmware update from November 3rd 2015 to install that allowed the controller to function with default layout in game but would not allow for button customization.

The December firmware update, one that brings a gui with additional customizations for lights, feedback and such, still does not seem to want to download on linux, but if you can get the `firmware.bin` file you can manually install it by holding right trigger while starting the controller bringing up a usb storage device allowing you to update. I have not tried this myself yet, but I provided a link to instructions below and will update this post when I try the fix myself.

Ask Ubuntu thread: [How do I get a Steam Controller working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686214/how-do-i-get-a-steam-controller-working/711081#711081)

Associated bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/steam/+bug/1498655

Updating firmware manually: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248647/unbrick-a-steam-controller