# Ubuntu 15.10 Steam Controller not working in games

Tags: drivers, games, steam

I have a steam controller to use with my HTPC running Ubuntu 15.10.  When I first plugged it in, it was entirely unrecognized.  According to this:

[How do I get a Steam Controller working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686214/how-do-i-get-a-steam-controller-working)

the controller should be automatically recognized in ubuntu 15.10.  It wasn't, so I followed the rules for earlier versions of Ubuntu and now it works fine in big picture mode (and desktop browsing) but is not recognized in most games.  It is `partially' recognized in some games, which is really odd. (only one button works)

The steam controller works fine on my windows 10 pc and is upgraded to the latest firmware version.  My wireless xbox360 controller works just fine.

Comment: Others, including me, are having this same problem: http://steamcommunity.com/app/353370/discussions/0/458604254430807981/