# Steam Controller works in Steam, but not in games under Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: games, steam

The Steam controller is running fine in Steam app's big picture mode, but when I load a game and try to use the controller, there's no response to in-game activity. I can use it, however, to open and navigate through the Steam menu by pressing the Steam button. (I already tried this solution, to no avail: [How do I get a Steam Controller working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686214/how-do-i-get-a-steam-controller-working?noredirect=1&lq=1))

How can I get the controller to work in games?

Running:
Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 x64
GNOME 3.24.1
Linux kernel 4.10.0-21-generic
Steam beta client (built May 26, 2017)

Answer (score 8):

Your issue may be resolved, but I have the exact same issue. After many research, I found in this thread ([How do I get a Steam Controller working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686214/how-do-i-get-a-steam-controller-working?noredirect=1&lq=1)) that you must have access to `/dev/uinput`. I just executed `sudo chmod 666 /dev/uinput` before launching the game and the Steam Controller worked wonderfully in game!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a tone.  I don't even have a Steam Controller.  I have a Logitech Rumble Pad 2.  And I'm on Linux Mint 19.  I did install steam-devices, but from what I could tell it made no difference.

Answer (score 5):

The quick answer:

```
sudo apt install steam-devices
```

The Long answer:

I haven't used the steam controller for half a year, and i just tried to see if it was working with Ubuntu 17.10 and

"No Controller Detected" as well as no "add Steam Controller" Option in BPMode.

All while 2 things were noticeable:
1/ it worked while plugged in (although still undetected!)
2/ In wireless mode it is totally unresponsive, except that it lights on and off when restarting the computer

So I knew the controller and dongle were basically functional.

This command should make it work:

```
sudo apt install steam-devices
```